# template_redirect for single posts w/ custom fields

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field

Is there any way I can use `is_single()` inside of my plugin's functions.php file? Currently, this is what my code looks like:

```
if(is_single()) :
    function my_template() {
        include(PLUGINDIR . '/supersqueeze/all.php');
        exit;
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template');
endif;
```

But for some reason, it is not working at all. If I remove `if(is_single())`, it works but is for all pages.

And then once I get that working, I'll need to filter it once more to see if the post has a certain custom field value, lets say the name will be `Design` and the value will be `Custom`.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're checking is_single() when your plugin is first loaded, before the global query has run, so is_single() still returns false.  You should move the is_single() check within your my_template function:

```
function my_template() {
    if(is_single() && have_posts() && 'Custom' == get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Design')) {
    include(PLUGINDIR . '/supersqueeze/all.php');
    exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template');
```